# Entering a zero-length string into a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with two fields (A and B). B is designed to show up after I have entered data into A.  I want to be able to enter anything into A. Access will not allow me to do this - B will not show up if I simply press Enter on my keyboard for field A (a zero-length string). What can I do to fix this? I have used the code below:

```
Private Sub A_AfterUpdate()
If A = "" Then
B.Visible = True
Else
B.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have this in mind:

```
Private Sub A_AfterUpdate()

    B.Visible = Not IsNull(A.Value)

End Sub
```

And you cannot "type" a *Null* value. Just leave the textbox empty.

Comment: So there is no workaround to leaving the field A `Null`, but still have B hidden? That is, if I were to leave the textbox for A empty, B will not show up unless I type in something and press enter. If A is left blank, B will not show up, but if I press enter, I will be stuck on A.

Comment: Right. The zero-length string problem has been solved, but now I can't have a null value specifically for A, since B won't show up.

Comment: But a textbox (normally) won't hold a zero-length string but will be Null if "empty". Even if it does (when bound to a field that has been set to allow ZLS), it looks as if it has a Null value, so when should B be visible and when not?

Comment: B should be visible after I do something as simple as pressing the Enter button in field A.
My understanding of ZLS vs Null is the difference between (no value vs value unknown). So if A was the first Name, and B was the last name, I want to be able to enter both a ZLS or a Null value (or anything else), before B pops up, since some people might not have a first name (ZLS, rare), or they might not have given me their first name (Null).
Side question: Typing "" would work for ZLS, but is not user-friendly. Is there a way to change this, without causing issues for the entering of a Null value?

Comment: ".. enter both a ZLS or a Null value (or anything else), before B pops up" ... covers any possible input, so just leave B visible at all times.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, but is it possible to leave B invisible until such a thing occurs?

Comment: You could use the _OnChange_ event of A to set `B.Visible = True`.

Answer (score 1):

> if I simply press Enter on my keyboard for field A (a zero-length string)

When a text box is left empty (as you seem to have described), Access interprets that as `Null`, not a zero-length string. If you want to specify a zero-length string you need to actually type `""` into the text box.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Is there a way to allow the user to enter null values in the same vein then? I have tried `If A = "" or IsNull(A) = True Then` ... But it still seems to prevent a user from entering a null value for A.